How to select the employees with highest consecutive attendance days?
I have a table containing id, date and present (0 or 1).
I need to select the employees with highest consecutive attending days.
Assume date column has no gaps. How can this be achieved?
This is what I tried, but doesn't work (I was trying to recursively define a new column):
with cte as (
Select id, date, 
(case when lag(present,1) over (partition by id order by date)=1 
      then lag(counter,1) over (partition by id order by date) +1 
  Else present)  as counter 
From Presence)

Select id from cte 
Group by id 
Having max(counter) = (select max(counter) from cte)

Is there a way to define the counter column in another way?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

case when present (select counter from cte where date = date - 1) + 1 else 0

Can you provide us with sample data and expected result, preferably on a dbFiddle site
